# Check values exists in another table

Tags: python, django

Sorry about my doubt, i'm a student. I have this scenario

```
    class Equipment():
        id
        name 
        ...

    class Alert():
        id
         ...
        pin
        value
       equipment_id
```

The tables (Equipment - Alert) have no relationship:

1. I need to check if the id of the Equipment table exists in the Alerts table
2. If there is  need to return A, if there is no return B, and return th to template

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hard to tell what you want to do, but you can do a combo of

```
# will give all equipment_ids in all alerts
alerted_equipment_ids = Alert.objects.values_list('equipment_id', flat=True).distinct()

# will filter Equipment and give those with alerts
alerted_equipment = Equipment.objects.filter(pk__in=alerted_equipment_ids)

# will get alerts that has a valid equipment-ID
alerts_for_alerted_equipment = Alert.objects.filter(equipment_id__in=alerted_equipment.values_list('pk', flat=True))
```